# How do I make all the containers have even height inside a column?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a case where I have some containers that should have the same height. But since each container has different text, it makes the height depend on this text. How can I make the height of these containers set to the highest height dynamically. So it should know which widget has the highest height.

Is there any widget I can use or any approach?

Here some code that I have:

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.amber[600],
        child: Text(
          'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.pink[600],
        child: Text(
          'Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Normally in this scenario, we would set a default height for the containers, for eg: 50 and do an ellipsis on bigger texts. Would that do for you?

Comment: Finding the tallest container and setting its height to other container is disastrous. What happens when one of your container has a very lengthy text and viewing it on your phone? All your containers will become so big that there are more empty spaces than text.

Answer (score 0):

[Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget may work for your use case.

Comment: How should I use it?
I just tried, but the height of the container still different

Answer (score 0):

***Finding the tallest container and setting its height to other container is disastrous.***

What happens when one of your container has a very lengthy text and viewing it on your phone? All your containers will become so big that there are more empty spaces than text.

Normally in this scenario, we would set a default height for the containers, for eg: 50 and do an ellipsis on bigger texts.

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 60,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: Text(
        'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        maxLines: 3,
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 60,
      color: Colors.pink[600],
      child: Text(
        'Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.',
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        maxLines: 3,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of exploring,
Here's my approach:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.amber[600],
            child: Text(
              'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.pink[600],
            child: Text(
              'Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

I need to add IntrinsicHeight then add the Column as child. And also need to set mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.max